# Is there anyway to stop the artillery shelling at Cima Leon: Centcom once liberated?

Tags: just-cause-3

I just liberated Cima Leon: Centcom while under constant artillery. I figured it would stop once I liberated it, but it's still raining down on me!  Is there anything I need to switch or other base I need to liberate to stop the shelling here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a storyline mission which will disable the Airstrike FOW for that base. Just keep doing storyline missions and you'll get to it.

Comment: Oh, was I not suppose to clear that island before continuing the storyline ?

Comment: Maybe technically, no, but Just Cause is a pretty open game, so if it's fun, do it!